# Modify LLVM Tracer to make Fault Injection

Tags: c++, dynamic, llvm, code-injection, fault

I want to modify the following dynamic LLVM tracer:

https://github.com/ysshao/LLVM-Tracer

to make a dynamic fault injection. Which changes should I make in the code? I'm a beginner using LLVM.

Best,

Answer (score -1):

you can't do any change to your code. just what you should do is configure the LLVM